# Generation of XSLT From XML

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have an XML File with very large content. 
I had an xsd file for that xml file.

For example : Please visit this link

XML CONTENT : http://formalmind.com/sites/default/files/blog/manual-testing.reqif

XSD For that XML : https://www.omg.org/spec/ReqIF/20110401/reqif.xsd

I need to display that xml in HTML page. For that i need XSLT.

Is it possible to generate XSLT for the given XML Automatically ? or is there is any other way to display in html Page?

Html Result Should be like

[HTML_OUTPUT_IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GAWh.png)

Thanks
Sivabalakrishnan

Comment: Neither an XML sample document nor an XSD schema defines one particular HTML format to represent such samples so it is not clear why you expect to be able to generate an XSLT stylesheet creating HTML automatically. You would need to have a schema for the particular HTML format you want the XML to map to, then you might be able to use Altova MapForce (although I have never used that tool). But in general the task to use XSLT to transform some XML to some HTML involves first choosing/creating the HTML you want and then to implement the mapping of your XML to HTML with XSLT template rules.

Comment: Thanks @Martin Honnen I had edited my question , please revisit and give an idea

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, but it's not clear that it's a useful approach. What information in the schema do you intend to use to generate your XSLT? You need to give some examples of constructs that you find in the schema, and the resulting XSLT rules that you want to generate.

There are two other options you should consider:

(a) writing a completely generic XSLT stylesheet, that handles any document regardless of its schema. For example, it could contain rules like this:

```
<xsl:template match="*[count(*)>1 and count(*)=count(distinct-values(*/node-name())]">
  <table>
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></td>
        <td><xsl:apply-templates/></td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
</xsl:template>
```

This rule says that if you encounter an element with 2 or more element children, and all the children have distinct names, then display a table containing the element names in one column and their values in another.

(b) writing a generic schema-aware (XSLT 2.0) stylesheet that handles any input document, but uses schema information from the type annotations on validated nodes to decide what output to generate. For example you might have a rule like this:

```
<xsl:template match="@*[data(.) instance of xs:decimal]">
   <xsl:value-of select="format-number(., '#,00', 'continental')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

which causes all decimal attribute values to be displayed using a format such as `3,14`.

Comment: Thanks @Michael Kay , I had edited my question , please revisit and give an idea

Comment: You have still given no clues as to what kind of HTML rendition you are aiming for.

Comment: I had added a link for the html image which iam looking for ! Thanks @Michael Kay

Comment: I don't think any kind of automation is going to get you that rendition. You need to bite the bullet and write some XSLT code.